# Is this a proverb in Quran? Are there other proverbs too?

Tags: quran

[Quran, Al'Araf (7), 40:](https://quran.com/7/40)

إِنَّ ٱلَّذِينَ كَذَّبُوا۟ بِـَٔايَـٰتِنَا وَٱسْتَكْبَرُوا۟ عَنْهَا لَا تُفَتَّحُ لَهُمْ أَبْوَٰبُ ٱلسَّمَآءِ وَلَا يَدْخُلُونَ ٱلْجَنَّةَ حَتَّىٰ يَلِجَ ٱلْجَمَلُ فِى سَمِّ ٱلْخِيَاطِ ۚ وَكَذَٰلِكَ نَجْزِى ٱلْمُجْرِمِينَ

Is `يَلِجَ ٱلْجَمَلُ فِى سَمِّ ٱلْخِيَاطِ` an Arabic proverb?

If it's a proverb, do we have other proverbs in Quran too?

**Update:**
By proverb, I mean a traditional saying, [as defined by Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proverb).

Comment: Please define or restrict "proverb" because the Arabic synonyms "مثل" and "حكمة" would almost apply to a large part of the qur'an! In fact the first word around 102 times in the qur'an and at least 34 of them fall under the meaning of مثل in Arabic!

Comment: @Medi1Saif, thanks for clarification request. I updated the question.

Comment: I personally won't call these proverbs. These are more like Arabic idioms, well known at that time (if not still) and well understood. Naturally, you'll find these "idioms" occasionally in the Quran.